# communicate between apps over network

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I'm trying to build an app that would be able query a database over wifi, I think I'd make two different apps. One running the database, receiving queries, and sending data to the other app, (on another device) querying the database. My problem is I can't find anything that could help me send simple SQL or JSON queries over wifi in an electron app.

If someone could just point me in the right direction or if someone has done this sort of thing before that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Hey @coolWinter you would need a database driver in nodejs , using this driver package you may use it's expose method and query database and process the ResultSet.

```
    var mysql = require('mysql');

    var con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "localhost",
      user: "yourusername",
      password: "yourpassword",
      database: "mydb"
    });

    con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      con.query("SELECT * FROM customers", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
      });
    });
```

Electron is basically a nodeJs using Chrome V8 Engine wrapped for desktop application - so there should not be any problem using any driver in electron application

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql
```